# how to get NAND Threshold voltage distribution using FTD2XX python

Tags: python-3.x, memory, flash-builder, spi, ftdi

I am trying to get Micron 3D NAND flash memory Threshold voltage distribution using FTD2XX python, but i am not getting command sequence. Can you suggest me suitable command sequence?

Unable understand how extract Vt distribution of 3D NAND (Micron)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i wanted to read threshold voltage distribution of micron 3D NAND flash memory with FT2232H FTDI minimodule using python code but i am not getting way to read their threshold voltage distribution.